# How to wrap text for an entire column using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I want to use Pandas, to wrap an entire column. I have already set the width for the columns now I just need to wrap the entire column as they are all in 1 line.

I do not need to edit the width of the columns, I want to wrap the text in the cells.

I can do this in Excel by clicking on "Wrap Text", see example below:

[image: before looks like this]

Desired output:

[image: after looks like this]

How can I apply wrapping on a column with Pandas and not manually in Excel ?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question and provide sample inputs and expected outputs?  See this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Ok done edited the post :)

Comment: Take a look at [.str.wrap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.wrap.html#pandas-series-str-wrap)

Comment: I saw that already but i don't understand what the "12" is doing.

Comment: It places at '\n' new line character after the 12 character.  What IDE are using for your python codng?  How are you displaying this dataframe?

Comment: I'm using CLI. Thats the problem.  i don't get how to integrate it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use solution modifying [example_pandas_column_formats](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html):

```
import string

long_text = 'aa aa ss df fff ggh ttr tre ww rr tt ww errr t ttyyy eewww rr55t e'
data = {'a':[long_text, long_text, 'a'],'c':[long_text,long_text,long_text],
        'b':[1,2,3]}       
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

```
#choose columns of df for wrapping
cols_for_wrap = ['a','c']


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('aaa.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

#modifyng output by style - wrap
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
wrap_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

#dictionary for map position of selected columns to excel headers
d = dict(zip(range(26), list(string.ascii_uppercase)))
print (d)
{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H', 8: 'I', 
9: 'J', 10: 'K', 11: 'L', 12: 'M', 13: 'N', 14: 'O', 15: 'P', 16: 'Q', 
17: 'R', 18: 'S', 19: 'T', 20: 'U', 21: 'V', 22: 'W', 23: 'X', 24: 'Y', 25: 'Z'}

#get positions of columns
for col in df.columns.get_indexer(cols_for_wrap):
#map by dict to format like "A:A"     
    excel_header  =  d[col] + ':' + d[col]
    #None means not set with
    worksheet.set_column(excel_header, None, wrap_format)
    #for with = 20
    #worksheet.set_column(excel_header, 20, wrap_format)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Woah haha im lost. lets say i have a excel file to read the columns and wrap based on columns. How would i change in that case. Your example is based on a string so i cant visualise how to do it.

Comment: My example is based by wrap by columns of dataframe - `cols_for_wrap`. Do you need something else? Can you explain more? Or what is necessary explain more in my solution?

Comment: i want to just open up the excel file and change the values in the entire columns C,D,E,F,G to be wrapped.

Comment: i don't get the first part where u did, long_text= 'aa aa ss df fff ggh ttr tre ww rr tt ww errr t ttyyy eewww rr55t e '  that divider is 2 different ways to do it?

Comment: Yes, then need instead `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` use `df = pd.read_excel('file')` if need pandas solution.

Comment: ok then, writer = pd.ExcelWriter('aaa.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') is writing to another file?

Comment: I think your input is dataframe and output is wrapped excel file. Is it True?

Comment: yes,  sure. So do you need input is excel file and output is wraped excel file?

Comment: lets say my input excel file already has colours and formatting done. after i do the wrap and save to another file will those formatting be gone?

Comment: I am worried you lost formating, because my solution working Excel file -> dataframe -> wraped excel file. And dataframe lost formating of excel file :( I think for your solution need another technology working with excel file directly and which not lost formatting. Maybe something macro of excel file (never do it, so I cant help you with this macro)

Comment: awww ok then last question, df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx') what if i want to read a sheet inside this workbook?

Comment: how about write to a specific sheet? pd.ExcelWriter('aaa.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

Comment: then use `xlsx = pd.ExcelWriter('aaa.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet1')`

Comment: Yes, you can check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-excel-reader

Comment: @Peter.k - It seems some wrong reassign, check variable names.

Comment: `excel_header =f"{xlsxwriter.worksheet.xl_col_to_name(col)}:{xlsxwriter.worksheet.xl_col_to_name(col)}"` works for columns greater than Z(26) too :)